# AppEngine - Remote API returning 401 and too-many-auth

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-oauth

I am trying to connect to an AppEngine instance with the remote API with something like this:

```
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = ".../path/to/key"
remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth(
    server.encode('ascii'), path, secure=True
)
```

Where the `path/to/key` points to a JSON file created in the Google Cloud (Beta), **API Manager -> Credentials -> Add Credentials -> Service Account**.  The service account "Can edit" per the **Permissions** panel.

When I run this I get an error like this on the console, corresponding to a 401 (as reported in the App Engine log viewer):

```
  File "/usr/local/share/app-engine-python/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 768, in ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth
    rpc_server_factory=rpc_server_factory)
  File "/usr/local/share/app-engine-python/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 835, in ConfigureRemoteApi
    app_id = GetRemoteAppIdFromServer(server, path, rtok)
  File "/usr/local/share/app-engine-python/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 569, in GetRemoteAppIdFromServer
    response = server.Send(path, payload=None, **urlargs)
  File "/usr/local/share/app-engine-python/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 258, in Send
    NeedAuth()
  File "/usr/local/share/app-engine-python/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 234, in NeedAuth
    RaiseHttpError(url, response_info, response, 'Too many auth attempts.')
  File "/usr/local/share/app-engine-python/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 85, in RaiseHttpError
    raise urllib2.HTTPError(url, response_info.status, msg, response_info, stream)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized Too many auth attempts.
```

I checked and the correct credentials seem to be set in `/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py:760` and should be passed to the remote api.

The `app.yaml` has the basic setting `- remote_api: on` under `builtins`.

This setup works for the local `dev_appserver.py`, so I am led to believe the problem is on the Google server/cloud settings.

I have tried both authentication schemes in **App Engine -> Settings -> Application settings** (Google Accounts API and Google Apps domain).

I followed the [Google Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) as fit as I could, but maybe I missed something?

It is probably also worth noting that from the command line:

```
$ GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=~/path-to-key
    remote_api_shell.py -s APPID.appspot.com --secure APPID
```

also gives the same 401 exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so what seemed to be necessary was:

1. Go to the appspot.com admin page.
2. Under Application Settings, enable Cloud Integration
3. Create a new service account in the *new* cloud console page API Manager (existing service accounts do not seem to work)
4. <strike>Switch to `remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApiFromServer`</strike> — on further inspection, it appears that `ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth` works fine.

At least after performing the above access works as expected.

I hope others similarly situated find this helpful.

Comment: I tried following this answer, but I couldn't get it to work. I have described my problem here in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39812525/getting-refreshing-due-to-a-401-when-trying-to-connect-using-remote-api Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Just encountered this issue and nothing here resolved it.
The only thing that worked for me is adding the `--secure` option to the remote shell command

```
$APPENGINE/remote_api_shell.py  --secure -s my-app.appspot.com
```

Answer (score 3):

For people using the remote api from the command line (`bulkloader.py`, `remote_api_shell.py` etc.), a 401 error might also happen if your appengine cookies are expired.

Try deleting them and authenticating again:

`rm ~/.appcfg*
gcloud auth login`

This could happen in cases where changes made to a Google account force logging out (e.g: enabling 2 factor authentication).

Comment: in my case, working with multiple professional and private GAE projects, simply rerunning the `gcloud auth login` resolved the error.

Comment: @BuffaloRabor you can also use `gcloud config set account` (`gcloud auth list` to see accounts), which doesn't prompt for the oauth2 screen and simply reuses tokens you've generated earlier. `gcloud auth login` is a bit more powerful, and `rm ~/.appcfg_cookies` is the most extreme solution.

I usually use `gcloud auth login` too, but it wasn't enough the time I enabled 2 factor authentication.