# Google app engine remote python console credentials/login?

Tags: shell, google-app-engine, authorization, credentials

Hi I am trying to start remote GAE shell with

python $GAE_SDK_ROOT/remote_api_shell.py -s your_app_id.appspot.com

"You don't need any additional authentication" says the GAE RemoteAPI page,
yet my command fails miserably with HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized Too many auth attempts.

I think I was able to do start it (with various degree of success for different apps) in some remote past, either with gmail credentials or some auth key from google cloud.

Please share your hints, or, ideally, drop a link to easy to follow step by step guide.

Also I cannot access Datastore Admin for that project
in online console
, if I click It invites to sing in, which fails. Recently, I got owner role, yet project was created by a person with a different email domain.

Comment: I had same issue and was able to google it and fix, just keep going

Comment: I tried to follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378616/appengine-remote-api-returning-401-and-too-many-auth yet got same error

Comment: @Ramiel some information on what exactly you did would be beneficial.

Comment: I found a comment stating the GAE bug might be related to custom domain use

Comment: @Serge you might have to set an oauth token using gcloud (even if you aren't using gcloud for App Engine development).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40349915/appengine-remote-api-shell-not-working-with-application-default-credentials-sinc

Comment: Removing old domain from settings referrer field resolved the issue.