# Appengine remote_api_shell not working with application-default credentials since update

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gcloud, remoteapi

I recently updated my gcloud libraries from 118.0.0 to 132.0.0 and immediately remote_api_shell no longer worked. I went through a number of permutations of re-logging in, to set the application-default credentials through gcloud, and to use a service account and environment variable. All permutations failed with the same error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mbostwick/google-cloud-sdk/bin/remote_api_shell.py", line 133, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/Users/mbostwick/google-cloud-sdk/bin/remote_api_shell.py", line 129, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Users/mbostwick/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/remote_api_shell.py", line 160, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/mbostwick/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/remote_api_shell.py", line 156, in main
    oauth2=True)
  File "/Users/mbostwick/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/remote_api_shell.py", line 74, in remote_api_shell
    secure=secure, app_id=appid)
  File "/Users/mbostwick/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 769, in ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth
    rpc_server_factory=rpc_server_factory)
  File "/Users/mbostwick/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 839, in ConfigureRemoteApi
    app_id = GetRemoteAppIdFromServer(server, path, rtok)
  File "/Users/mbostwick/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 569, in GetRemoteAppIdFromServer
    response = server.Send(path, payload=None, **urlargs)
  File "/Users/mbostwick/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 259, in Send
    NeedAuth()
  File "/Users/mbostwick/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 235, in NeedAuth
    RaiseHttpError(url, response_info, response, 'Too many auth attempts.')
  File "/Users/mbostwick/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc_httplib2.py", line 85, in RaiseHttpError
    raise urllib2.HTTPError(url, response_info.status, msg, response_info, stream)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized Too many auth attempts.
```

After back revving through 131.0.0 and 130.0.0, I just went back to 118.0.0, re-logged in and everything worked fine.

I did not update the running application after updating gcloud, as I'm in the middle of a release cycle at the moment, so that may have been the issue, but any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TL;DR**: This was fixed in gcloud version 134

**Original answer**: Run

```
gcloud auth application-default login --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

Now your remote shell should work again.

**Details**:
I think this was broken by the 128.0.0 update, along with the changes to the `gcloud auth login` command. The old tokens have the following scopes (according to Google's tokeninfo endpoint):

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
```

The new tokens from `gcloud auth application-default login` without any options only have:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

This is documented in `gcloud auth application-default login --help`

**Version 134 details**: The scopes requested are now:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

See discussion at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/ptc-76K6Kk4/9qr4601BBgAJ

Comment: Thanks, this looks very promising. Do you happen to know if there is an open issue with Google for this, either with respect to the code or documentation?

Comment: I am not aware if there is or not. I did post on the app engine Google Group to try and get it some attention. I don't have much faith in the public issue tracker:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/ptc-76K6Kk4

Comment: This was also a problem with firebase rest API, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443525/firebase-applicationdefaultcredentials-doesnt-work-in-dev-appserver/40539525#40539525